# VUE app change dev server from localhost:8080 to my-testing-web-address.com

Tags: javascript, vue.js, localhost, webpack-dev-server, devserver

I have a VUE application and I need to run it on an external link not on localhost.

I tried to create a

```
vue.config.js

devServer: {
    host: 'http://my-testing-web-address.com',
    port: 8080,
    ...
}
```

and set the devserver, but still no changes

when I run

```
npm run serve
```

It says

```
App running at:
- Local:   http://localhost:8080/ 
- Network: http://192.168.0.100:8080
```

It's any way to set up an external devserver?

Comment: did you `npm run build`?

Comment: yes and for npm run build it's ok, but I need to have the devserver running on the same url, because I'm doing the design changes and if I'll run build every time, a lot of time will be waste.

Comment: Is this for showing changes to your client who is viewing externally?

Comment: the company's policy is to work directly on the server, so the project need to be develop not locally, but remote...

Answer (score 5):

```js
{
  module.exports = {
    devServer: {
      host: 'projectname.local'
    }
  }
}
```

Full details here: https://stevencotterill.com/snippets/vue-cli-using-a-custom-domain

Answer (score 4):

In vue.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  }   
}
```

Comment: Currently `disableHostCheck` does not seem to "exist" while using Vue "^2.7.14". Thank You anyway, I think it helped me discover the solution I presented.

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the similar entry to `module.exports` in "vue.config.js" helped:

```js
devServer: {
  allowedHosts: ['(...).tunnelmole.com']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use the ending "**.com**" in a test urlI recommend using your-domain.test with the ending "**.test**"

See the correct configuration, how it should look:

into vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
transpileDependencies: true,
devServer: {
host: 'vue-custom-domain.test',
client: {
  webSocketURL: 'ws://vue-custom-domain.test:8080/ws',
},
  }
})
```

More info in: https://www.conteudopertinente.com.br/vue3/vue-change-url-from-localhost8080-to-custom-domain/